# IBM MobileFirst Analytics Console Total Sessions number with session independent mode configured

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I'm working in a project with session independent mode configured (worklight.properties file). In my Analytics Console I can see 68 total adapter calls but the total sessions number shows 0. Is this behavior right? I think must have 1 session created at least.

In this [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/03/29/sessions-in-mfp-7-1-analytics/#indepMode) I found information related, however 0 sessions versus 68 adapter calls sounds rare.

Comment: Just to confirm - the adapter calls were all answered?

Comment: And were the adapter calls made from a device or hitting REST endpoints?

Comment: @VivinK yes they were all answered. I don't understand your second question, could you explain a little more?

Comment: Where the adapter calls made from within the application running on the device or you invoked the adapter using REST clients?

Comment: @VivinK a few calls were made it from a mobile device, another from an emulator plugged to a stress test suite. I guess both are considered devices (physical and virtual). I'm not using a REST client.

Comment: Do you use WLResourceRequest or WL.Client.invokeProcedure to invoke your adapters?

Comment: @VivinK we are using WL.Client.invokeProcedure to invoke our adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is expected. This is because in session independent mode, session count increases when a protected resource is invoked and an OAuth token is issued from the server. This does not appear to be happening in your case with the use of WL.Client.invokeProcedure().

If you use WLResourceRequest API to invoke your adapter resources , the session count will increase on the first resource request as a new token will be issued from the server. More details on the API [in this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html).

Session count will not increase again until the token expires, a protected resource is called, and a new token is issued from the server.

The information is available in the link you have already [referenced](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/03/29/sessions-in-mfp-7-1-analytics/#indepMode).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and references.